# Discrete Math: Inductions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Find a formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{(i+1)!}$ and prove that it holds for all $n\geq 1$.

I'm not sure how to go with this problem can someone help please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\dfrac{i}{(i+1)!} = \dfrac{1}{i!} - \dfrac{1}{(i+1)!}$

Comment: I don't get what I have to do next

Comment: Can someone give me more hints of how to do this problem.

Comment: @Alex: add those difference up

Comment: I get 1 - 1/2 + 1/2 -1/3 + 1/3 .... but i'm not sure then what happens after that?

Comment: @Alex: [Telescoping Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Answer (score 0):

Your last comment is wrong. Using what LAcarguy wrote, what you have is (for $n=4$) $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{(i+1)!}=\frac {1}{1!} -\frac {1}{2!}+\frac {1}{2!} - \frac {1}{3!} + \frac {1}{3!} -\frac {1}{4!}+\frac {1}{4!}-\frac {1}{5!}$$ Do you see what is left ?

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: So wouldn't the final answer be 1 - 1/(i+1)! ??

Comment: @Alex. Almost ! $1 - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ would be better.